# Update slider ui value from array

Tags: jquery, html, css

Slider ui picks values from array (it can also be manipulated with 'plus' and 'minus' buttons) - however it doesn’t update the numbers in the input field until the mouse is 'unclicked' which is not very user friendly.

[Here is a link to Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/martynava/jrx8rz79/9/)

```js
$(function () {
  var sizes = [ "0 years", "1 year", "2 years", "3 years", "4 years", "5 years", "6 years", "7 years" ];
  $("#slider-range-max3").slider({
    range: "max",
    min: 0,
    max: sizes.length - 1,
    step: 1,
    create: function(event, ui) {
      $("#sup").val(sizes[0]);
    },
    change: function (event, ui) {
      $("#sup").val(sizes[ui.value]);
      $(".sup").text(sizes[ui.value]);
       var value = $(this).val(),
      button = $("#sup").val(sizes[ui.value]);
      setTimeout(function () { /* update text after jQM refreshes slider */
        button.text(custom[value]);
    }, 0);
      
    }
  });

  $("#plus3").click(function () {
    var value = $("#slider-range-max3").slider("value");
    var step = $("#slider-range-max3").slider("option", "step");

    $("#slider-range-max3").slider("value", value + step);
  });

  $("#minus3").click(function () {
    var value = $("#slider-range-max3").slider("value")
    var step = $("#slider-range-max3").slider("option", "step");

    $("#slider-range-max3").slider("value", value - step);
  });
});
```

```html
<div id="quote-input" class="slider-input">
<div id="minus3" class="minus"><span>-</span></div>
<div id="plus3" class="plus">+</div>
        <input type="text" id="sup" class="slider-value">

          
<div id="slider-range-max3" class="slider">
<span class="ui-slider-handle"></span>
</div>
```

I've found a similar solution on [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/0vaoLoq5/) and tried to apply to my case, however unsuccessfully.

The added code which doesn't work:

```
   var value = $(this).val(),
  button = $("#sup").val(sizes[ui.value]);
  setTimeout(function () { /* update text after jQM refreshes slider */
    button.text(custom[value]);
}, 0);
```

I am not sure how to get it to work.

Comment: *until the mouse is 'unclicked'* what does it mean?

Comment: He means when you release the mouse, then the value is updated. Ofcourse that's what a click event does, after the mouse has been released it'll execute the code.

Comment: This is probably not the best way to explain it but value is only updated once mouse button is released. I am trying to get the slider value to update while its handle being dragged.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To update the values while sliding, you need to use the `slide` event instead of the `change` event

```
  $("#slider-range-max3").slider({
    range: "max",
    min: 0,
    max: sizes.length - 1,
    step: 1,
    create: function(event, ui) {
      $("#sup").val(sizes[0]);
    },
    slide: function (event, ui) {
      $("#sup").val(sizes[ui.value]);
      $(".sup").text(sizes[ui.value]);
       var value = $(this).val(),
      button = $("#sup").val(sizes[ui.value]);
      setTimeout(function () { /* update text after jQM refreshes slider */
        button.text(custom[value]);
    }, 0);
```

Comment: Thanks, but this won't fix the problem as buttons work fine anyway. The problem is someone in a slider ui change function: change:                  function (event, ui) {
      $("#sup").val(sizes[ui.value]);
      $(".sup").text(sizes[ui.value]);
       var value = $(this).val(),
      button = $("#sup").val(sizes[ui.value]);
      setTimeout(function () { /* update text after jQM refreshes slider */
        button.text(custom[value]);
    }, 0);

Comment: Works like charm! Thank you for your fix

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow :)